# How to logout specific user? IdentityServer4

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, logout

I am trying to create functionality where admin can deactivate users in the system. I know about `HttpContext.SignOutAsync();`  and `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);` which can singout current user, but how can i do it for specific user by their id/username etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you really need to store their session in the backend somehow. `CookieAuthenticationOptions.SessionStore` (of type`ITicketStore`) is the extensibility point that allows you to add backend persistence to the cookie middleware.